# How to convert unicode font to ansi

Tags: windows-7, fonts, unicode, ansi

I am trying to use Bengali writing product [Avro Keyboard](http://www.omicronlab.com/) but since it uses Unicode by default so working with Adobe products like Photoshop, PageMaker, etc… are not working at all.

When I change the mode to ANSI *then* AVRO works but I also have to change the font to ANSI coded font (Unicode fonts dont work). Now it will be very kind if someone help me with any one of them, please I really need the answer:

1. Collection of Bengali ANSI coded fonts (which I searched but unsuccessful to find any).
2. Method to convert these Unicode fonts to ANSI fonts (if its possible, I don’t know).
3. A workaround to use them on Adobe products and still using the Unicode fonts.

Comment: "ANSI" is not a charset.

Comment: Sorry my knowledge in encoding etc is very low. I just tried to explain the problem so i told what i know.

Comment: There are some ANSI fonts available on the [app's site](http://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html), did you bother to try them?

Comment: Yes, i have checked that already and with just 2 fonts installed which look just the same, its same as having nothing. Hope you understand thats why i asked for the other two options if possible. Its so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have an ANSI Bengali codepage. If your applications do not support Unicode, you won’t be able to display Bengali text in them.